# Boot Repair - GRUB2 MENU dpkg

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, usb

I am currently running Ubuntu on a 7.5GB flash drive, as my 256GB SSD  (partitioned as a Linux system) does not seem to be able to boot. When I do boot it from the BIOS menu, it comes up with a strange GRUB menu that has a black screen. The screen indicates I can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> for a bunch of commands, but none of them seems to be of any help.

This problem occurred because I tried to erase my disk and reinstall Ubuntu, but my USB was "dirty" (or at least there was an error message that claimed this was the case).

So I decided to *Try Ubuntu* on a flash disk to try and recover my 256GB SSD using boot repair. It gave me this command to run in the terminal:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" dpkg --configure -a
```

This command didn't appear to do anything. Here is the [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yzg9kqvPTN/).

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? I ordered an Ubuntu flash drive for $30 from Amazon just now, so I can maybe run a fresh install on a working disk (presuming the dirt was the problem).

Comment: While you should be able to boot with UEFI Secure boot on, have you tried with it off? And then press Escape, right after UEFI/BIOS screen and before grub menu would normally appear? If you get grub menu, try recovery boot or second line in menu.  If not use advanced mode in Boot-Repair and do a full reinstall of grub & included latest kernel. And any other commands it suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

go to disks in ubuntu (the application)

format the 256gb ssd (your harddrive, in an appropriate format, and make sure you erase the old content to decorrupt it).

Trial and error really... for me anyway. Be careful not to delete your own data if you plan on keeping it though.